# Fix blurry text in jsPDF

Tags: canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fMo4wpbfp2r7c3TwrUJG?p=preview) I have a div that should be converted to PDF using `jsPDF` and `html2canvas`. Problem is that the text in the output PDF is blurry and the border instead of dashed is solid. Is there a way to fix this?

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="download()">Convert to PDF</button>
<br/><br/>
<div id="div1" style="border:1px dashed red;background-color:yellow">
  <h4>This text will be converted to canvas, then to image and then to PDF</h4>
</div>
<p>
This text will not be included
</p>
```

Javascript

```
var download = function(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("div1"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('sample2.pdf');
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I have the same problem, looking for solution, I will let you know if I find something :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/html2pdf.js/0.9.1/html2pdf.js"></script>
```

- jspdf.min.js
- html2canvas.js
- html2pdf.js

```
var element = document.getElementById('divContents');
html2pdf(element, {
                margin: 0,
                filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 2, logging: true },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4' }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I this help me

I defined

```
var w = 1000;
var h = 1000;

var download = function(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("div1"), {
            scale: 2,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          context.scale(2,2);
          context["imageSmoothingEnabled"] = false;
          context["mozImageSmoothingEnabled"] = false
          context["oImageSmoothingEnabled"] = false
          context["webkitImageSmoothingEnabled"] = false
          context["msImageSmoothingEnabled"] = false
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('sample2.pdf');
            }
        });
    };
```

I hope that works for you

Comment: any explanation?  why declare w and h if never use them?

Comment: Multiple declared variables that are never used, using multiple variables that are never defined, no explanation as to what anything does. -1.